# What is a holomorphic foliation?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

For a smooth foliation $F$, there are three equivalent definitions:

1. the leaves of $F$ are tangent to a smooth vector field;
2. the foliation chart $\phi:U\to \mathbb R^k\times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ is smooth;
3. the leaves are smooth immersed submanifolds and the local holonomy is uniformly smooth.

When talking about a holomorphic foliation, we can likewise define it in three ways. Are they equivalent? If not, what's the canonical definition.

Comment: The first definition doesn't make sense to me. If $F$ is just a collection of subsets of a manifold, each tangent to some smooth vector field, then $F$ might not be a foliation. What is the precise definition you have in mind? Same for the other two.

Comment: All of the usual definitions of smooth foliation have obvious analogues, replacing the word "smooth" by "holomorphic" everywhere, and the same proofs of their equivalence work by again replacing the word "smooth" by "holomorphic" everywhere. Try it and see if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks. I should define in advance that $F$ is a foliation and I'm trying to say something about the regulation of this foliation.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Sorry for rudely bringing you back to an old question. The definition of smooth foliation that I remember requires that a foliated chart be a diffeomorphism $\phi : U \subset M \to I^k \times I^{n-k}$ (where $I$ is an open unit interval) such that, for every $p \in I^{n-k}$, the preimage $\phi^{-1}(I^k \times \{ p \})$ is contained in a leaf. Does this definition work in the holomorphic setting if I replace $I$ with an open polydisc?

Comment: @pyon: yes, that works, or even just $I$ being a disk, since you already have products of $I$ in the definition of foliated chart. The foliated charts have to be biholomorphisms, not just diffeomorphisms, for the definition of holomorphic foliation.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Thanks! And, yes, of course the foliated charts of a holomorphic foliation have to be biholomorphisms, that was clear to me right from the beginning.

Comment: I believe a good reference for this question is the book "Complex Algebraic Foliations" by Lins Neto and Scárdua (Maybe a bit  biased because I first learned these things from the brazilian version of this book)